# "missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int" error occur at a field of a struct defined in same .h file

Tags: c++

I looked at many similar quastions, but all of them are having two seperate .h files and having problem when one of the class is having a field of type of class defined in another .h file.
How ever, my problem is happening within one single .h file.
In this .h file, I defined a struct:

```
struct inventory_entry_drawn_info {
    int text_x_start;
    int text_x_end;
    int y;
};
```

and I also have a class:

```
class inventory_entry{
public:
    ...
    inventory_entry_drawn_info drawn_info;
    ...
}
```

Then, when I build my project, I was given such error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (compiling source file ..\src\npctalk_funcs.cpp)   Cataclysm-lib-vcpkg-static  C:\Users\h\Documents\GitHub\Cataclysm-DDA\src\inventory_ui.h    127

Comment: Looks like the compiler's confused because it hasn't found `inventory_entry_drawn_info` yet. Ensure `inventory_entry_drawn_info` is defined somewhere before `inventory_entry`.

Comment: Right, and does your `npctalk_funcs.cpp` actually *include* that header file of yours?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: @user4581301 that's nice. I just placed the struct in front of the class then the error never come out any more.